# RAMdisk causes Synaptics touchpad to stop working

Tags: laptop, synaptics-touchpad

I have been having a problem lately with my Synaptics V1.7 touchpad. Everytime I start RAMdisk, my laptop's touchpad stops working. I have searched all over the internet, but can't find a single solution. I have only found one, inconvenient "workaround" - use external USB mouse however much of the time that is not viable. I have also tried disabling and reenabling the touchpad device, however the settings window always freezes and never actually disables, much less reenable. Hard reboot is the only way to fix crashed setting window

any solution would be awesome. Thank you

Comment: I would report this problem to both companies as a bug.

Comment: Ok. It might be worth mentioning though that this is only a recent thing. I haven't updated anything (my laptop isn't even connected to the internet - in fact I'm using my phone to type this)

Comment: I know Synaptics pushes driver updates through Windows Update from time to time.  I assume you keep your system patched.